# Unable to inject cxf service in @ManagedBean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, cxf

I am working on a project with the following technology -

1. Spring 3.2
2. CXF 2.2.12
3. Primefaces 3.5

I have created & successfully published the below web service -

```
<bean id="loginService" class="com.cloudsym.service.login.LoginServiceImpl" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="loginServiceWSId" implementor="#loginService" address="/iLoginService" />
```

I have defined a client as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"       
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
   xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
    ">

<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout="360000" />
</http-conf:conduit>

<bean id="clientWS" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
</bean>

<bean id="loginServiceClient" class="com.service.login.ILoginService" factory-bean="loginServiceFactory" factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="loginServiceFactory" parent="clientWS">    
    <property name="serviceClass" value="com.service.login.ILoginService"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:9090/MYAPPWS/iLoginService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="loginServiceBean" class="com.controller.login.LoginController">
    <property name="loginService">
        <ref bean="loginServiceClient"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the corresponding class  is as below -

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

import com.service.login.ILoginService;
import com.vo.login.LoginVo;

@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@ViewScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ILoginService loginService;

public void fetchLoginDetails() {
    try {
        //String clientBeansPath = "classpath:com/resources/spring/client-beans.xml";
        //ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(clientBeansPath); 
        //classPathXmlAppContext.start();
        //ILoginService loginService = (ILoginService)classPathXmlAppContext.getBean("loginServiceClient");
        LoginVo loginVo = loginService.getLoginData("1");
        System.out.println("IN LOGINCONTROLLER");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Autowired
public void setLoginService(ILoginService loginService) {
    this.loginService = loginService;
}
```

}

When I call the above method from index.xhtml-

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginBean.fetchLoginDetails}" ajax="false" />
```

I get the error as below -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.controller.login.LoginController.fetchLoginDetails(LoginController.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But when I try using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext (The commented code) I am successful with the service calls and get the desired result.

I am not sure why the setter injection is not working.......

Thanks

Comment: In your LoginController class, replace ILoginService loginService with ILoginService loginServiceClient;

Comment: Also change your mutator accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Prasad for your response, The above code shows no of ways I have tried. (Forgot to comment the code while sharing here)    `<bean id="loginService" class="com.cloudsym.service.login.ILoginService" factory-bean="loginServiceFactory" factory-method="create"/>
    
    <bean id="loginServiceFactory" parent="clientWS">    
        <property name="serviceClass" value="com.cloudsym.service.login.ILoginService"/>
        <property name="address" value="http://localhost:9090/MYAPPWS/iLoginService"/>
    </bean>` **But the above is not working either**

Comment: Aha,
Did you include <context:annotation-config /> in the client xml where you defined the beans?

Comment: I have tried it too, While debugging I found out when the class LoginController is resolved via clients-bean.xml the setter for ILoginService loginService in LoginController is not null but when I call the method fetchLoginDetails from `<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginBean.fetchLoginDetails}" ajax="false" />` loginService  is null hence the NullPointerException is thrown.I am not sure what am I missing while defining the beans.

Comment: "loginBean" is not Spring context managed bean, "loginServiceBean" is spring context managed bean(which instantiates the loginservice bean). So when your commandbutton is pointing to loginBean.fetchLoginDetails,  loginservice is null.